# The label tag mixed with comment in sentiment analysis data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, nlp, data-cleaning

I have below data frame and my label column as u can see is part of sentence row and its separated by \ character. My question is how can I delete these zero and ones or replace them with " " character and transition them to new Label column beside this comment column?

thanks for you're help.

[image]

Comment: You are loading the data wrong. Please provide more information.

Comment: why wrong? my data has 47969 rows and 1 column and each rows are sarcastic comment from reddit dataset I can just upload the capture of part of it. In you're idea how can I loading it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading your dataset wrong.

It is a tab-separated file. You are loading it as a comma-separated file.

Try adding `\t` as a separator while loading the file. This will create two columns. Also, you can add column names while loading.

Example:

```
pandas.read_csv(filename, sep='\t', names=['tag', 'text'])
```